# Getting error in Anaconda Notebook saying "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" when using tensorflow library

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I installed TensorFlow to notebook using 'pip install tensorflow' and when I tried to use that library, I get the error 'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'

For example, I get this error when I put any one of these shown below.:
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization

This error does not show in **Google Colab** for the same code I have. I looked into other answers in StackOverflow but none seems to work. I tried upgrading Tensorflow and reinstalling libraries, but nothing works. Please Help!!! Thank you!

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using (`pip show tensorflow`)? Which python version? Do you have a CUDA install? Are you using anaconda?

Comment: Python version is 3.8.8. TensorFlow version is 2.8.0. I am using Anaconda and MacBook Air M1.